# blinn phong lighting creating strange results

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d, glm-math

I'm creating a raycaster and trying to use global illumination as a shading method
I've calculated the intersect of a a sphere and cube as well as their normals

creating each of the separate ambient, diffuse and specular result in shading the object as expected however
overall once adding them together as shown in the code below

```
glm::vec3 n = surfaceNormal(position, intersect);
glm::vec3 lightStart = glm::vec3(-10, 1, 10);//light points in 3d space
glm::vec3 lightDir = glm::normalize(lightStart - intersect); // direction towards light source
glm::vec3 viewDir = glm::normalize(cam.pos - intersect); // direction towards camera
glm::vec3 midDir = glm::normalize(lightDir + viewDir);//mid point between light and view

glm::vec3 lightColor = glm::vec3(1, 1, 1);//color of light
glm::vec3 objectColor = color ;

float shinyness = 10.0f;
float ambientStr = 0.1f;   

///ambient
glm::vec3 ambient = lightColor * ambientStr;
///diffuse
glm::vec3 diffuse = lightColor * glm::max(glm::dot(n,lightDir), 0.0f);
///specular

//ks * light color * facing * (max(n dot h))

glm::vec3 specular = lightColor * facing(n, lightDir) * 
std::pow(glm::max(glm::dot(n, midDir), 0.0f), shinyness);

glm::vec3 outColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
return outColor * objectColor * 255.0f;
```

the facing method returns 1 if the cross product of (n,lightDir) > 0 else it returns 0
this is to avoid lighting faces pointed in the wrong direction

this is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: As a side note, this seems to have nothing to do with OpenGL

Comment: @meowgoesthedog its part of an opengl raycaster

Comment: It would only be about OpenGL if you actually *use it* to render the scene, e.g.  with GLSL. This is just a software-only raycaster with no relevant OpenGL code (I'm assuming you are using OpenGL to *blit* the rendered buffer).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog ah i understand, yeah im not using GLSL to render, thanks for the correction

Comment: How are you storing the output pixels, e.g. 24 bit RGB or 3 floats? What happens if you divide the result by some experimental constant (could fix the "clamping" seen here)?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog the output are float values for color being drawn straight to screen. ive just experimented dividing the output by 3.0f stops the weird results, with a darker output, but im not sure why ?

Comment: Could be a normalization issue - some of the values were above 255.0 so they were wrapped around starting from 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*255f` was suspicious already (typical usage of OpenGL works with color components in the range of [0...1]), and you added a comment

> the output are float values for color being drawn straight to screen.

It is a simple overflow issue then. Your weight is a sum of 0.1+[0...1]+[0...1] (ambient, diffuse and specular), which falls into [0.1 ... 2.1], and when you multiply it with a color component larger than 0.5 (approximately, 1/2.1 is the precise limit), their product exceeds 1. Then this number is multiplied with 255, and the result will be above 255, and when truncated to a byte, it "starts over" from black, component-wise.

Based on the code you show, you could probably try something like

```
return glm::min(outColor * objectColor * 255.0f, glm::vec3(255f, 255f, 255f));
```

but there may be a better function for that.